# Nextjs 13: application in dev mode crashes after change code

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dockerfile, next.js13

Recently I upgraded my application to Nextjs v.13 and now I get crashes of dev server when change something in the code. Example of how to get a crash: Remove a function/variable that used somewhere -> save -> crash with this code

```
app-name | thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: NulError(208, [10, 32, 32, 27, 91, 51, 49, 109, 120, 27, 91, 48, 109, 32, 85, 110, 101, 120, 112, 101, 99, 116, 101, 100, 32, 99, 104, 97, 114, 97, 99, 116, 101, 114, 32, 39, 92, 48, 39, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 44, 45, 91, 27, 91, 51, 54, 59, 49, 59, 52, 109, 47, 115, 114, 118, 47, 115, 114, 99, 47, 102, 101, 97, 116, 117, 114, 101, 115, 47, 99, 111, 109, 112, 97, 110, 121, 47, 99, 111, 109, 112, 97, 110, 121, 77, 97, 110, 97, 103, 101, 114, 47, 99, 111, 109, 112, 97, 110, 121, 77, 97, 110, 97, 103, 101, 114, 46, 99, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 46, 116, 115, 120, 27, 91, 48, 109, 58, 57, 48, 58, 49, 93, 10, 32, 27, 91, 50, 109, 57, 48, 27, 91, 48, 109, 32, 124, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 60, 47, 62, 10, 32, 27, 91, 50, 109, 57, 49, 27, 91, 48, 109, 32, 124, 32, 32, 32, 41, 59, 10, 32, 27, 91, 50, 109, 57, 50, 27, 91, 48, 109, 32, 124, 32, 125, 59, 10, 32, 27, 91, 50, 109, 57, 51, 27, 91, 48, 109, 32, 124, 32, 0, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 58, 32, 27, 91, 51, 49, 59, 49, 109, 94, 27, 91, 48, 109, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 96, 45, 45, 45, 45, 10, 10, 10, 67, 97, 117, 115, 101, 100, 32, 98, 121, 58, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 83, 121, 110, 116, 97, 120, 32, 69, 114, 114, 111, 114, 10, 10, 83, 116, 97, 99, 107, 32, 98, 97, 99, 107, 116, 114, 97, 99, 101, 58, 10, 32, 32, 32, 48, 58, 32, 60, 117, 110, 107, 110, 111, 119, 110, 62, 10, 32, 32, 32, 49, 58, 32, 60, 117, 110, 107, 110, 111, 119, 110, 62, 10, 32, 32, 32, 50, 58, 32, 60, 117, 110, 107, 110, 111, 119, 110, 62, 10, 32, 32, 32, 51, 58, 32, 60, 117, 110, 107, 110, 111, 119, 110, 62, 10, 32, 32, 32, 52, 58, 32, 60, 117, 110, 107, 110, 111, 119, 110, 62, 10, 32, 32, 32, 53, 58, 32, 60, 117, 110, 107, 110, 111, 119, 110, 62, 10, 32, 32, 32, 54, 58, 32, 60, 117, 110, 107, 110, 111, 119, 110, 62, 10, 32, 32, 32, 55, 58, 32, 60, 117, 110, 107, 110, 111, 119, 110, 62, 10, 32, 32, 32, 56, 58, 32, 60, 117, 110, 107, 110, 111, 119, 110, 62, 10, 32, 32, 32, 57, 58, 32, 60, 117, 110, 107, 110, 111, 119, 110, 62, 10, 32, 32, 49, 48, 58, 32, 95, 90, 90, 78, 52, 110, 111, 100, 101, 49, 52, 84, 104, 114, 101, 97, 100, 80, 111, 111, 108, 87, 111, 114, 107, 49, 50, 83, 99, 104, 101, 100, 117, 108, 101, 87, 111, 114, 107, 69, 118, 69, 78, 85, 108, 80, 57, 117, 118, 95, 119, 111, 114, 107, 95, 115, 69, 95, 52, 95, 70, 85, 78, 69, 83, 50, 95, 10, 32, 32, 49, 49, 58, 32, 119, 111, 114, 107, 101, 114, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 97, 116, 32, 47, 110, 111, 100, 101, 45, 118, 49, 57, 46, 53, 46, 48, 47, 111, 117, 116, 47, 46, 46, 47, 100, 101, 112, 115, 47, 117, 118, 47, 115, 114, 99, 47, 116, 104, 114, 101, 97, 100, 112, 111, 111, 108, 46, 99, 58, 49, 50, 50, 58, 53, 10, 32, 32, 49, 50, 58, 32, 60, 117, 110, 107, 110, 111, 119, 110, 62])', /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/napi-2.10.9/src/error.rs:322:1
app-name  | stack backtrace:
  app-name  |    0:     0xfffe6dc53898 - <unknown>
  app-name  |    1:     0xfffe6dc78440 - <unknown>
  app-name  |    2:     0xfffe6dc4c7c8 - <unknown>
  app-name  |    3:     0xfffe6dc536a4 - <unknown>
  app-name  |    4:     0xfffe6dc55310 - <unknown>
  app-name  |    5:     0xfffe6dc55050 - <unknown>
  app-name  |    6:     0xfffe6dc559a4 - <unknown>
  app-name  |    7:     0xfffe6dc55784 - <unknown>
  app-name  |    8:     0xfffe6dc53d28 - <unknown>
  app-name  |    9:     0xfffe6dc554c8 - <unknown>
  app-name  |   10:     0xfffe6a5f257c - <unknown>
  app-name  |   11:     0xfffe6a5f2764 - <unknown>
  app-name  |   12:     0xfffe6cc2fe88 - <unknown>
  app-name  |   13:     0xfffe6a8369b4 - <unknown>
  app-name  |   14:     0xaaaab7302b90 - _ZZN4node14ThreadPoolWork12ScheduleWorkEvENUlP9uv_work_siE0_4_FUNES2_i
  app-name  |   15:     0xaaaab7f433ec - uv__work_done
  app-name  |                                at /node-v19.5.0/out/../deps/uv/src/threadpool.c:318:5
  app-name  |   16:     0xaaaab7f4723c - uv__async_io
  app-name  |                                at /node-v19.5.0/out/../deps/uv/src/unix/async.c:163:5
  app-name  |   17:     0xaaaab7f5951c - uv__io_poll
  app-name  |                                at /node-v19.5.0/out/../deps/uv/src/unix/epoll.c:374:11
  app-name  |   18:     0xaaaab7f47c5c - uv_run
  app-name  |                                at /node-v19.5.0/out/../deps/uv/src/unix/core.c:406:5
  app-name  |   19:     0xaaaab72778a4 - _ZN4node21SpinEventLoopInternalEPNS_11EnvironmentE
  app-name  |   20:     0xaaaab7381b3c - _ZN4node16NodeMainInstance3RunEv
  app-name  |   21:     0xaaaab72f821c - _ZN4node22LoadSnapshotDataAndRunEPPKNS_12SnapshotDataEPKNS_24InitializationResultImplE
  app-name  |   22:     0xaaaab72fb1f8 - _ZN4node5StartEiPPc
  app-name  |   23:     0xffff861ad5bc - <unknown>
  app-name  | fatal runtime error: failed to initiate panic, error 1167804944
```

What can be wrong?